# Trying to display image taken from camera intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

I'm Currently trying to take a photo from the default camera intent from the `MainActivity` and then put that image in an `ImageView` in the same activity.

I'm saving the images such that the image taken overwrites the previously taken image (In this case, I call the image `test.jpg` and I store it in sdcard)

The problem I have with my code right now is the `ImageView` displays the photo taken the previous time the application ran.

Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
ImageView imv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv);
    Uri uri = null;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test.jpg";
    try
    {
        uri = takePhoto(path);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imv.setImageURI(uri);
}

private Uri takePhoto(String path) throws IOException
{
    File photo = new File(path);
    photo.createNewFile();
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    return fileUri;
}   
}
```

Comment: http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/picture-selection-from-camera-gallery/

Comment: Where is your `onActivityResult` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set image in `onActivityResult` as below:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent ata)                                     
          {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       imv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imv.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }}}
```

Comment: Thanks. This made it work. What does the onActivityResult do? Could you explain this to me?

Comment: When the user is done with the subsequent activity and returns result back to current activity, the system calls your activity's `onActivityResult()` method.  The result `Intent` returned by Android's Camera app provides a content `Uri` that identifies the captured image.In order to successfully handle the result, you must understand what the format of the result `Intent` will be. Doing so is easy when the activity returning a result is one of your own activities. Apps included with the Android platform offer their own APIs that you can count on for specific result data.

Comment: `onActivityResult` Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the `requestCode` you started it with, the `resultCode` it returned, and any additional data from it. The `resultCode` will be `RESULT_CANCELED` if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final int     PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0 ;
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                 Intent data) {
             if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    imv.setImageURI(uri);

                 }
             }
         }
```

Set the image in onactivity result it will show new Image taken from the camera .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private Uri takePhoto(String path) throws IOException
    {
        File photo = new File(path);
        photo.createNewFile();
        if(photo.exists())
            photo.delete();
        photo = new File(path);
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        return fileUri;
    }
```